# Resolving ambiguous initializer from multiple frameworks

Tags: swift, frameworks, protocols, initializer, ambiguity

I have declared an initializer in an extension on a built in protocol type.

```
extension SomeProtocol {
    init(fromData: Data) { // my code here }
}
```

A framework that I use also declares an initializer for the same protocol with the same function signature.

So when I try to invoke my initializer, I get an error about ambiguity:

```
let myObject = SomeProtocolConformingObject(fromData: data) // error
```

I know that you can specify top-level functions from a framework like so:

`SomeFramework.topLevelFunction()`

But how can I specify to use my initializer or the framework's initializer without changing the function signature?